# Push notification background killed by the user

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification

Push is being received while app is in the background killed by the user, when the user hits the push notification it opens the app and it doesn't crash but it is closed immediately.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.

        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

        // Print message ID.
        print("The userInfo is: \(userInfo)")

        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }
```

The previous method is not even called, or may be it is but I don't know how to debug it, since the application is not running.

Here's the notification object that I send via the server:

```
apns: {
                payload: {
                    aps: {
                        alert: {
                            title: messageObject.authorName,
                            body: messageObject.content,
                        },
                        sound: "notification.wav",
                        category: "ChatViewController"
                    }
                }
            }
```

That is what is send via the server. The notifications work when the application is in background and not killed, or when the application is in foreground.

Comment: When app was killed and you clicked on the notification then you need to handle that scenario in appDelegate method didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

Comment: How can be you so sure that the application is not crashing instead of just get closed ?

Comment: I figured out that the application was indeed being closed, however the ```UNNotificationResponse``` is nil. How can this be that in background this object is not nil, but when the app has been killed is not?

Answer (score 0):

I think so when user click on the notification while your application is killed or in background or foreground, below method would be executed. And you have to test it one by one.

First of all check that whether yo are able to see the popup as soon as the application runs when you click on notification. Just copy, paste this code in your **AppDelegate** Class and comment your **didReceiveRemoteNotification** method and then check whether your application crash or not.

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    guard let object = response.notification.request.content.userInfo as? [String : AnyObject] else {
     return 
  }

    self.normalPopup()
 }

 /// Alert Popup, if user not exist in our database.
func normalPopup() {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Test", message: "Show pop up window.", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
    }))
    self.window?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true)
}
```

If popup window shows, then comment the **normalPopup** function and replace that function with below code. Then check whether your application crash or not while application killed.

```
    Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
```

Please Lemme know if you are still facing the same issue.

Comment: I figured out that the application was indeed being closed, however the ```UNNotificationResponse``` is nil. How can this be that in background this object is not nil, but when the app has been killed is not?

Comment: First of all am not clearing about your point what you are trying to say. Soo far what I understand from your point of view. When you click on any notification at that time OS will active your application and When your notification delegate method triggered UNNotificationResponse is not nil.  You will get the payload object in this delegate method.

Answer (score 0):

If you use firebase for that first you should define it on `application(_ application:, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` like underneath:

```
  
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
          // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
          UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

          let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
          UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
          let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
          UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
          application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }
        
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        return true
    }
```

Also you can Handle notifications when app is ran, with this func:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        
        if let messageID = userInfo["gcm.message_id"] {
          print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }
        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
       
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }
```

and

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
        
        if let messageID = userInfo["gcm.message_id"] {
          print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
        
    }
```

and you should set new token to Messaging with this method:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

        Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
        let token = deviceToken.map { String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0)}.joined()
        print(token)
        
    }
```

at the end you can handle notifications with below extension

```
// [START ios_10_message_handling]
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

  // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
        
        if let messageID = userInfo["gcm.message_id"] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

    //*************************
    // Handle push notification message automatically when app is running 
    //*************************
    print(userInfo)

    // Change this to your preferred presentation option
    completionHandler([[.alert, .sound]])
  }

  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                              didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                              withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo["gcm.message_id"] {
      print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    //*************************
    // Handle push notification message after click on it
    //*************************

    print(userInfo)

    completionHandler()
  }
}
```